# Why does Windows Security stop prompting for my smart card credentials (the "more options" is not showing)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, smartcard

I'm currently in a Windows 10 domain environment that uses smart card authentication. We are using ActivClient 7.1.0.213 for reading the smart cards. I use a user smart card to login as a user (which has only user certificates on it.) I have a separate smart card for administrative tasks, which has its own certificate.

When I run a program as an administrator or connect to the network drive, a Windows Security prompt will appear asking for my credentials. At this point, there will be a small blue  text link that says "More choices" at the bottom. Clicking this will enable me to pick a certificate from my smart card and then type in a pin.

The issue I am having, however, is that this "More choices" option seems to randomly disappear. Because of this, I am unable to select my certificate and thus cannot connect the network drive or run the program. The only solution so far I have found that works is to restart my computer.

What could be causing this and how can I troubleshoot/fix it?

Comment: @nightmare637 - Please edit your question to include that vital fact.

Comment: How are your certificates setup?  Do you have a user certificate and an Administrator certificate?  Are both certificates on the same card?  All these configuration choices make a huge difference.  Are you using a third-party client like ActivClient to manage the smart card?  Please edit your question instead of submitting vital information as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Ramhound. I have updated my question with the vital information - sorry for not thinking to include it earlier! Regarding the questions in your comment, yes I have a user certificate and and an admin certificate. They are both on separate cards. Yes, I am using ActivClient to manage the smart cards. I also updated my question with this information - thanks again!